# $f$ holomorphic, calculate $f(1+i)$ with two informations about $f$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ be a holomorphic function, knowing that :

1) $Im(f'(x+iy))=6x(2y-1)$

2) $f(0)=3-2i$

Find $f(1+i)$.

There is nothing in my notes, but I have read online that $f'(x+iy)=\displaystyle{\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,y)+i\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(x,y)}$, which I don't really understand, but does this mean that $Im(f'(x+iy))=\displaystyle{\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(x,y)}$ $\left(\mbox{and so }=\displaystyle\frac{-\partial u}{\partial y}(x,y)\right)$ ?

In that case :

I can deduce that $v(x,y)=(2y-1)3x^2+t(y)$ and $u(x,y)=-6x(y^2-y)+s(x)$, and using $f(0)=3-2i$, I know $t(0)=-2$ and $s(0)=3$. Since $f$ is holomorphic, I also know that $\displaystyle{\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}}$, therefore $6y-6y^2+s'(x)=6x^2+t'(y)$, meaning $t'(y)=6y-6y^2$ so $t(y)=3y^2-2y^3+t(0)=3y^2-2y^3-2$, and $s'(x)=6x^2$ so $s(x)=2x^3+3$.

Finally :

$u(x,y)=-6x(y^2-y)+2x^3+3$ and $v(x,y)=(2y-1)3x^2+3y^2-2y^3-2$

Therefore : $f(1+i)=u(1,1)+iv(1,1)=5+2i$.

Is that correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $z=x+iy,$ suppose $f(z)=2z^3-3iz^2 +az +3-2i,$ where $a$ is a real constant. Then $\text {Im}\, f'(z) = 12xy - 6x,$ and $f(0) = 3 +2i.$ Any such $f$ therefore satisfies the conditions. Since $a$ is an an arbitrary real constant, there is no way to uniquely determine $f(1+i).$

Comment: Can you explain how you determined $f$ ? Is that the only possible "format" for the function ? If so, should I then conclude that : $f(1+i)=(-7+a)+i(2+a)$ ?

Comment: Okay I actually understood how you found $f$, sorry. Thank you very much !